# Install pre-configured Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, clone

I have about 60 machines I want to install Windows XP on using a USB drive. What I would like to do is have a pre-configured install. Meaning all the necessary software, and bookmarks in the browsers set.

All of these machines are nearly-identical, with slightly different RAM, some different models of the same make of processors, etc.

I thought about just setting one machine up how I want, clone the drive, and install from there, although I am unsure if that would work.

I have used nLite before to make something close, but it was unable to get the level of setup I was looking for. In the end, I want to format the drives and just start new with a completely pre-configured setup.

What options do I have available?

Comment: (1) Support for XP has ended and (2) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302577

Comment: Use SysPrep which is used for exactly what you described.  Seriously take into consideration that Windows XP support has ended, so if you plan to connect these machines to the internet, you are seriously at risk. In the very near future neither Firefox nor Chrome will work with Windows XP.

Comment: @Ramhound, your comment could be the candidate to be the answer.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia - I don't answer questions about `Windows XP`.  There are plenty of existing answers to questions similar to this with more then enough information to get the author started.  My commentary on Windows XP, isn't an answer, so I literally have nothing to submit as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in comments, Windows XP is not supported anymore!

but

you could use:

[sysprep tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302577)

or make an [answer file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314460)

or if a windows server is available to you, you could use [WDS] role to install windows through network (some things are needed, if you wanted to use this solution, search for prerequisites)

Answer (score 0):

You can write an INF file, like my hivefix.  http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/84600-hivefixinf/

This is pretty good at fixing windows 2000/xp.  I've used it many a time.