# Install pre-configured Linux distribution over USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, opensuse

I have a few PCs that I need to install a pre-configured version of linux onto from a USB.

The purpose of these machines is to operate as a hypervisor for some VM's I need to run.  The problem is I have only figured out a way to install a fresh copy of some linux distro, not a pre-configured version.

I have found a question super similar to the one that I have ([Install pre-configured Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/939040/install-pre-configured-windows-xp)) but it is for Windows XP only. I need pretty much exactly what this individual needed but for a linux distribution.

Some of the Linux distros I am considering are (CentOS, Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, RHEL).

Any help is appreciated!

Best,
Conner

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this in the future and has the same question:

I figured out a way that would work for me.  So what I did is I installed ubuntu server onto a server and then used clonezilla to make a copy of that drive and then I can "restore" it onto other computers, basically imaging all of those newer machines.

Here is the video I followed to complete this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS6VhLDw-io)

Cheers
Conner

Comment: Without using a configuration management tool (puppet/chef/etc) or a custom install setup (using kickstart for RH like distros or a custom pre-seed for Debian like distros) this is the quickest and easiest option.